# Didn't Jscript.net have most of the TypeScript features?

Tags: typescript, jscript.net

I am ignorant about TypeScript. But from what I have read in beginner articles about it, I dont see anything "new" that is "great" as the adopters and advertisers claim it to be.

[1] Syntax-wise didn't JScript.net already offer everything that JavaScript/Jscript had, albeit for running on the dot net platform.

[2] Is it that TypeScript either does not need dot net or does not only run on dot net?

Why did not MS just advertise Jscript.net more? I dont mind that it does not have all the modern features that other languages have. I just mind that it was treated not good enough.

This is not a language war triggering question. I just am confused that the company already made a tool A which allowed coder to express their ideas in a certain way. They treated it like an outcast. And now they create another tool B which looks the same though with some differences, which I do not know from a lay person's point of view. I am like WHY WHY WHY?

Comment: [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) was a dialect of ECMAScript supported only in Internet Explorer. As such, it did not have the type annotation like TypeScript has, nor any of the advanced features of ECMAScript like classes, arrow functions, etc. [JScript.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET) does allow the use of type annotation, but does not mandate it. As its name implies, it requires the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript runs in all browsers.  JScript (and JScript.Net) do not.  Typescript compiles down to Javascript.

This means you can run Typescript code in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, Safari, etc.

This is not true for JScript.Net.

There are plenty of other differences but this one is huge.  This means JScript.Net should be compared more with Python or Node and not with Typescript.  Typescript was designed from the ground up to be able to fit seamlessly with existing Javascript code.  Javascript modules can use compiled Typescript modules and vice versa.  This could never be the case for JScript.Net.